# Using sd as a generic function in R

Tags: oop, r, r-s3

If I a have a class called `foo`, then it is straightforward to overload the `summary` function

```
summary.foo = function(x, ...) print("bar")
```

However this technique does not work with the `sd` function, that is

```
> bar = createFooClass()
> sd.foo = function(x, ...) print("Hi")
> sd(bar)
  error: is.atomic(x) is not TRUE
```

What is the correct way of overloading this function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can hijack any non-generic function, make it (S3) generic and set the original version to be the default version. For example:

```
## make an S3 generic for sd
sd <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("sd")
## take the usual definition of sd,
## and set it to be the default method
sd.default <- stats::sd
## create a method for our class "foo"
sd.foo = function(x, ...) print("Hi")
```

A final step, if this is in a package, is to add a `...` argument to `sd.default` to allow passing of package checks:

```
formals(sd.default) <- c(formals(sd.default), alist(... = ))
```

giving:

```
> args(sd.default)
function (x, na.rm = FALSE, ...) 
NULL
> args(stats::sd)
function (x, na.rm = FALSE) 
NULL
```

This then gives the desired behaviour:

```
> bar <- 1:10
> sd(bar)
[1] 3.027650
> class(bar) <- "foo"
> sd(bar)
[1] "Hi"
```

This is documented in [section 7.1](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Adding-new-generics) of the Writing R Extensions manual

Comment: Better to email R-devel and request that `sd` (or better, `var`) be made generic.

Comment: @hadley agreed, but as well as the need for R Core to maintain this, there is a performance hit when making something generic, hence the wording and advice in the R Ext. Manual.

Comment: I don't buy those excuses. Why should mean by generic and not var?

Comment: @hadley They aren't my excuses ;-) (and I do agree with you) Anyway you'd be a bit stuck waiting for R Core to implement this before you could use it - so the "hijacking" method is still valuable until such a time as R Core did release a stable version of R with `sd()` as a generic.

Comment: Sorry I should've been more clear with my comment - sometimes you need to give R-core a hard time before they will implement clearly needed changes.

Answer (score 4):

You need to define a new generic for `sd`.

The easiest way is to use S4, because it handles the default "sd" method automatically:

```
setClass("foo", list(a = "numeric", names = "character"))

setGeneric("sd")

setMethod("sd", "foo", 
          function(x,  na.rm = FALSE){
              print("This is a foo object!")
              callNextMethod(x@a)
              })

tf <- new("foo", a = 1:10)
sd(tf)
#[1] "This is a foo object!"
#[1] 3.027650
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the code of `sd()`---it effectively dispatches internally.  In other words, it is not a generic function but a plain old regular function.

The easiest may just be to modify `sd()` to branch on class foo.

Comment: Funnily enough that's what I did, but it just seemed "wrong" and a bit awkward.