# Use data() as a generic S4 function

Tags: r, r-s4

I'm trying to define a new `data` method for a `foo` class. My `foo` objects follow the following structure:

```
setClass(Class = "foo", 
    representation = representation(
        data = "data.frame", 
        id = "character",   
        wl = "numeric"
    )
)
```

The `data` method I'm trying to create is actually accessing the contents of the `@data` slot:

```
setMethod("data", "foo",
    function(object)
        object@data
)
```

I've been looking at the [section 7.1](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Adding-new-generics) of the Writing R Extensions manual, but it only deals with S3 classes. I also had a peek at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728342/using-sd-as-a-generic-function-in-r), but without success:

```
setGeneric("data", function(object, ...) standardGeneric('data'))

setMethod("data", "ANY", utils::data)

setMethod("data", "foo",
  function(object)
    object@data
)
```

When loading the package:

```
> data(mtcars)
Error in function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function "data", for signature "data.frame"
```

Answer (score 5):

Pierre,

The first argument of `data` is `...` (not `object`!), so you need some special considerations for the dispatch. `? dotsMethods` discusses that.

Often (e.g. `cbind`, `rbind`), a quick & dirty solution is to use S3 method notation for these functions

```
data.foo <- function (...) {
   x <- list (...) [[1]]
   x@data
}
```

However, I guess you are in trouble here because the original data function uses the unevaluated name of the argument, and the error message suggests that it is evaluated (does make sense: how could R know which class the argument has if it doesn't evaluate?) before the original data function is called.

So in the end it may be much easier to use some other name than data () to access your data slot.

(Your wl slot makes me think of wavelengths: if you are setting up a class for spectroscopic data, have a look at [hyperSpec](http://hyperSpec.r-forge.r-project.org) - it may provide already what you need).

Comment: Hi Claudia, and thanks for your answer. I'm of course aware of your work on hyperSpec. I'm indeed setting up a class for spectroscopic data - very much a toy project to learn S4 classes, and test some soil-spectroscopy ideas. You can check it out [here](https://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/inspectr/), but this is much smaller a project than hyerpSpec!

Comment: Hi Pierre, thanks. 
As my data slot is rather central, I use `[]` and `[[]]` to access it.

You'd also be welcome to subclass from hyperSpec (which is the product of me learning S4...) or join the hyperSpec developers.

Answer (score 0):

What helped me (I am in the `S3` world) was to create default function that calls `data()` from the basic `utils` package:

```
data.default <- function(...){
 utils::data(...)
}
```

Then dispatch behaves as expected:

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
```